# PCs on same subnet can't access IIS served website - Server can access own pages

Tags: php, windows-7, iis-7

I am using Windows 7 in a Workgroup (no homegroup).

I have set up IIS and PHP on the "server" and can see the following page, but only when browsing to the URL from the server: http://localhost/phpinfo.php

Authentication on ISS is turned OFF for everything and authorization rules are set to Allow / All Users.

From another PC in the workgroup, I can ping the server. However, when I browse to the above URL from another PC the browser times out with the error "server not responing."

What are some reasons that I would not be able to access the URL from other PCs in the same workgroup in the same subet?

---

sorry, chaps. It still doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

A couple of possibilities immediately come to mind

- IIS might only be listening on the loopback interface (I can't remember the full usage for windows netstat command, run netstat from a command prompt, it'll show you what IP/interface is listening via what ports - you want something like "*:80"
- Windows Firewall is blocking

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I think you'll have to install php-support on iis: http://php.iis.net/

Comment: I belieive that I have. As stated "have set up PHP and a http://localhost/phpinfo.php on the server, which I can finally see ... on the server."